# Change the SHELL used in TI Code Composer Studio's auto-generated Makefiles on Windows 10

Tags: code-composer

I need the `makefile` generated by TI Code Composer Studio 10 to use `SHELL = sh.exe` instead of `SHELL = cmd.exe`. The insertion of the SHELL line seems to be specific to TI and not Eclipse. I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried setting environment variables at the system level and in the project build settings. I've tried running TI CCS from a bash shell hoping it might pick up its own environment. I've also looked through the Eclipse sources for [generating the makefile](https://github.com/MentorEmbedded/cdt/blob/master/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/src/org/eclipse/cdt/managedbuilder/makegen/gnu/GnuMakefileGenerator.java#L1179-L1183).

Example:

Everything from `SHELL` to just before the `-include` line is TI specific.

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

SHELL = cmd.exe

CG_TOOL_ROOT := C:/ti/ccs1040/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_20.2.5.LTS

GEN_OPTS__FLAG := 
GEN_CMDS__FLAG := 

ORDERED_OBJS += \
"./msp430fr60x7_1.obj" \
"../lnk_msp430fr6047.cmd" \
$(GEN_CMDS__FLAG) \
-llibmpu_init.a \
-llibmath.a \
-llibc.a \

-include ../makefile.init
```

Reason: gmake creates batch files for commands like `echo` and our computers have security software that block randomly created batch files from running. If run from bash/sh, gmake doesn't use intermediate batch files.

Update: I may have a workaround by telling the project to invoke gmake like this: `sh.exe -c gmake.exe args`. That isn't working fully though as the args do not get passed.

Answer (score 1):

[After confirming with TI that the SHELL is hardcoded](https://e2e.ti.com/support/tools/code-composer-studio-group/ccs/f/code-composer-studio-forum/1050460/how-to-change-the-shell-in-auto-generated-makefiles-on-windows-10-to-sh-exe/3886742#3886742), this workaround is the solution.

You'll need to:

- Create a make.sh shell script to run the real gmake.exe
- Create a makefile.defs to fix some SHELL and RM variables inside the TI generated makefile
- Install another sh.exe. I used the one installed with Git for Windows. The cygwin sh.exe that comes with the TI compiler doesn't work. *This is a shame, because it would be nice to have a solution not requiring another tool.*

First, modify your project build settings to run the make script. In TI Code Composer Studio:

Project Menu -> Show Build Settings -> CCS Build -> Builder

- [ ] Uncheck "Use default build command"
- Build Command:    `C:/Progra~1/Git/bin/sh.exe ${PROJECT_ROOT}/make.sh ${CCS_UTILS_DIR}/bin/gmake -k -j 8`

*Note: You have to use the MS-DOS short path for "Program Files," because it's 2021, and Eclipse can't handle spaces in a path.*

Create `make.sh` in the `PROJECT_ROOT` directory:

```sh
#!C:/Progra~1/Git/bin/sh.exe

# The cygwin provided shell from TI doesn't work with make. Use the one from Git instead or even SourceTree's embedded Git shell.
# In TI CCS, Project -> Show Build Settings -> CCS Build -> Builder -> Build Command (Uncheck Use default build command)
# Build Command:    C:/Progra~1/Git/bin/sh.exe ${PROJECT_ROOT}/make.sh ${CCS_UTILS_DIR}/bin/gmake -k -j 8

echo "$@"

# debugging
#echo $#
#env | sort

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo Nothing to do. >&2
    exit
fi

export MAKESHELL="$SHELL"
# echo MAKESHELL is \'$MAKESHELL\' inside the script, but will be translated to the DOS path inside make.

"$@"
```

Create `makefile.defs` in the `PROJECT_ROOT` directory. The Eclipse generated makefile includes this file at the very end allowing it to override any settings set by TI.

```
# The invoking shell sets MAKESHELL so we can grab it here.
SHELL = $(MAKESHELL)
RM = rm -f
$(info "MAKEFLAGS is $(MAKEFLAGS)")
$(info "MAKECMDGOALS is $(MAKECMDGOALS)")
# $(info "SHELL is $(SHELL)")
# $(info "CWD is $(CWD)")
# $(info "PATH is ${PATH}")
```